# How can I debug a Firebase Android Studio app that fails an upload with Permission Denied?

Tags: android, firebase, debugging, google-cloud-storage, permission-denied

I followed the procedure on Google Cloud to register my application by package name with Firebase, installed the resulting google-services.json file in the project’s app folder, and selected the bucket listed in that JSON file with the Kotlin sequence:

```
val firebaseStorage = Firebase.storage("gs://my-buckets-name.appspot.com")

val pictureRef = firebaseStorage.getReference("first_picture.jpg")
```

Note: my-buckets-name is not the name of my bucket.

But the upload task fails with a Permisson Denied exception, as shown in the LogCat subwindow.

I have no problem uploading files with the gsutil command on Windows 10 to the same bucket.

I tried making my bucket (briefly!) available allUsers, with NO SUCCESS. Any suggestions for how to debug this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Per a request, here are what I believe are the rules from the Firebase web-based console:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And what is this "if request.auth != null" all about?  What if request.auth is NULL?  Where is this set in the Android programming?

The URL is:

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-buckets-name/storage/my-buckets-name.appspot.com/rules
```

Where again I substituted the fake "my-buckets-name" for the real name of the bucket.

And here is the file upload programming from my Android app.  Parameter "thePath" is the path to the .JPG I want to upload; path has been verified:

```
private fun uploadToGoogleCloud(thePath : String)
{
    val firebaseStorage = Firebase.storage("gs://my-buckets-name.appspot.com")
    val pictureRef = firebaseStorage.getReference("first_picture.jpg")

    val theFile = File(thePath)
    val uriFile = Uri.fromFile(theFile)

    if (uriFile == null) {
        display.text = "Failed to get a URI file from " + thePath
        return
    }

    var uploadTask = pictureRef.putFile(uriFile)

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener {
        display.text = "Upload to Google Cloud failed: " + it.message  //always comes here
    }.addOnSuccessListener {
        display.text = "Upload to Google Cloud completed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Permission errors are due to security rules.  Please edit the question to show the *actual* client code that access an object, and the rules on the bucket that are supposed to allow it be to accessed.

Comment: The reason your uploads with `gsutil` work, is because `gsutil` runs with administrative privileges and bypasses Firebase security rules.

Comment: Thanks for your requests, Doug S.  Please see updated entry.

Comment: All: Removing the `if request.auth != null` from the rules solves the problem.  Still leaves me with a lot of questions, but I am so pleased to have gotten this upload to work!

Comment: By removing that condition you are actually leaving your bucket open for anyone to read and write it and that is not secure, is that what you want to achieve? If you leave this condition in your code, you will be allowing authenticated users to read and write to your bucket, so the problem is probably being generated by either lack of authentication of the user making the request.